# Youtube Pinging url info android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-debug

I am just doing a r&d on youtube video details. When we play a video in youtube and I can see in logs I am getting youtube pinging urls like below. This url contains details about the video with so many fields in it. Just wanted to discover the field details using in this. For an example :  cos : client device os

```
2020-08-13 20:27:10.674 28998-29030/? W/YouTube: Pinging https://s.youtube.com/api/stats/
qoe?cat=otfp
&cl=326137115
&ei=vlQ1X_n7OqTv4-EP186SuAc
&event=streamingstats
&feature=g-high-crv
&fexp=1714250%2C11216291%2C11219238%2C11219427%2C11220773%2C11221415%2C11221467%2C11221545%2C11221622%2C11221637%2C11221998%2C11222045%2C11222259%2C23744176%2C23839597%2C23844961%2C23850473%2C23857950%2C23858057%2C23862346%2C23880389%2C23882502%2C23883098%2C23884386%2C23890966%2C23893440%2C23900512%2C23903525%2C23907595%2C23910738%2C23916821%2C23918272%2C23918465%2C23918598%2C23925789%2C23927906%2C23928299%2C23928508%2C23928881%2C23928959%2C23930220%2C23931938%2C23934090%2C23934970%2C23935733%2C39783783%2C39788273%2C39789494%2C39791816%2C39792462%2C39792569%2C39792647%2C45170005
&ns=yt
&plid=AAWsw4RfLVtkVejV
&cpn=cysrzFFV3MdJlLGY
&cplatform=mobile
&cbr=com.google.android.youtube
&c=android
&cmodel=xmodel
&cos=Android
&csdk=28
&cbrver=15.32.34
&cver=15.32.34
&cosver=9
&cbrand=XYZ
&vis=0.213:5
&conn=0.222:3
&vfs=1.705:134:135::i
&cplayer=ANDROID_EXOPLAYER
&bh=9.109:5.86
&cmt=9.109:4.811
&fmt=134
&vc=1514264000
&afs=1.705:140::i
&sur=1.491:3
&bwe=1.705:115231.63
&view=1.705:1080:607
&bat=0.208:0.830:1,9.160:0.830:1
&rate=1.277:1.0
&vps=0.000:N,1.506:B,1.865:PL,9.109:N
&bwm=1.865:502514:0.207,9.109:861761:0.153
&user_intent=1.253
&ctmp=pmqs:dt.22300745;lmq.720;dir.none,ibws:2
&seq=1
&docid=(scrubbed)&referrer=(scrubbed)
```

If anyone can help me with, that would be great..